# @react-native-community/geolocation NativeModule.RNCGeolocation is null

Tags: react-native, expo

I am a beginner in React-Native and I would like my app to be able to geolocate the phone.
To do so I would like to use [@react-native-community/geolocation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation).

I thus ran:

```
yarn add @react-native-community/geolocation
npm install
```

I wrote the line `import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';` and ran `expo start`.

I immediately get this error:

> @react-native-community/geolocation NativeModule.RNCGeolocation is null.

It gives me different ways to fix this, but I am not using cocoaPods and when I use `react-native link @react-native-community/geolocation` nothing changes (except I can't open the project on emulator).

Here are the commands to reproduce my problem with a blank project:

```
expo init
yarn add @react-native-community/geolocation
npm install
expo start
```

I don't get what I am doing wrong. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

1. DO you mean quitting and run expo start again?
2. I am using react native 0.6+
3. Yes I am

Here are the commands to reproduce my problem with a blank project:

"expo init

yarn add @react-native-community/geolocation

npm install

expo start"

I don't get what I am doing wrong 
Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

some ideas:

1. Try to rebuild the app from command line
2. Are you using a react-native 0.59 or lower? If so, [check for the manual install](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation#manual-installation-react-native-059-and-lower)
3. Are you using expo?

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your import from

`import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';`

to

`import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';`

Comment: NB: First re-run the application soon after installing @react-native-community/geolocation. Sometimes this resolves the issue. But if it still returns Null. Then change your import of your library to above.

Comment: Don't forget also to include this statement just after the imports " navigator.geolocation = require('@react-native-community/geolocation');"